# "..." in every action in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

First I want to clarify that I'm new in node.js and I'm not a linux user, so the cmd isn't my thing.

Every time I try to do something, for example

```
sudo npm install express@2.6.5 (as it's in a sitepoint ebook example)
```

or

```
node example.js (as another tutorial)
```

Every time, the response is a "..." in the screen (http://www.screencast.com/t/dx6VZhsVtl), so my 3 questions:

1. Why this happens (I'm missing some configuration or something)?
2. How to install packages (as the ... is always the response)
3. When I run a program, I don't have to specify the absolute path, just the file?

Comment: Usually that means it's expecting more input, ie there's more for you to do before it executes the command.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to run the file example.js, but you're still running a [node REPL session](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) (indicated by the `>`, see the link for more details). Press Control+C a few times to exit to get back to regular terminal (it should show something like `username@machineName:`).

To run a node *file*, use `node [filename]`.

To open a node REPL session, simply use `node`.